# How to get the checkbox valu from below code

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
newTextBoxDiv.html(
'<td border="2">'+number+'</td>'+
'<td>'+grouptext+'</td>'+
'<td style="display:none">'+groupVal+'</td>'+
'<td>'+itemText+'</td>'+
'<td style="display:none">'+itemId+'</td>'+
'<td>'+cuttingText+'</td>'+
'<td style="display:none">'+cuttingId+'</td>'+
'<td> 
 <input type="text" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" 
 name="textbox' + counter + '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" size="13" />
 </td>'+
'<td> <input type="checkbox" name="samples"/> </td>'+
'<td> 
 <input type="text" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" size="8" 
  name="textbox' + counter +'" id="textbox1' + counter + '" value="" size="13" />
 </td>'
);
newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#example");
```

Now how can i get the check box true false values please help me

Comment: I give up on trying to format this thing. Please try to make your source code more readable. You might also want to consider a better way of dynamically generating your markup.

Comment: Please be more clear. What have you posted and what have you asked? You have posted about div and asking for check box value

Comment: Question seems like he just want to get the value of check box using JQuery. May be we could have had lesser code

Comment: @Daff. Can you or some one consider approving my edit. Its more readable now and I don't have any privileges to do it myself

Comment: Thanks, that works a lot better. Now if any of the answers given works for you mark them as accepted, otherwise people will stop answering your next questions.

Answer (score 2):

after the edit by @Daff it seems like you can use the below code...

```
$("#example").on("click",function(){

var val = $(this).find(":checkbox[name='samples']").val();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Later within the same block of code:

```
var isChecked = newTextBoxDiv.find('input[name="samples"]').is(':checked');
```

Or, in another context:

```
var isChecked = jQuery('#example').find('input[name="samples"]').is(':checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `.is(':checked')` it returns boolean

```
$('input[type="checkbox"][name="samples"]').click(function(){
    alert($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2jZM2/1/

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
$(':checkbox',newTextBoxDiv).each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('checked'));
})
```